# Store Boolean attribute?

Tags: python, boolean, save, python-xarray

I'm working with xarray and want to store a Boolean as attribute in a Dataset. As long as the Dataset is still an object, this works fine, but as soon as I want to write it to netCDF, this (of course?) doesn't work anymore. I get:

```
TypeError: illegal data type for attribute b'testattr', must be one of dict_keys(['S1', 'i1', 'u1', 'i2', 'u2', 'i4', 'u4', 'i8', 'u8', 'f4', 'f8']), got b1
```

What would be the best way to store a Boolean in the netCDF then, so that it can easily be parsed again when loading the file into an xarray Dataset again? String?

Comment: I would say byte, but only because it's the smallest datatype available

Comment: Yes, that's what I did then as well: converted the boolean entries to 0/1 and made a `uint8` data type. But still...